# Wrong Base URL Keycloak Deploy on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

i have a problem when deploy the Keycloak Server on AWS EKS
here is my configuration:

`Deployment.yaml`

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: my-keycloak
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: my-keycloak
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: my-keycloak
>     spec:
>       containers:
>         - name: my-keycloak
>           image: jboss/keycloak
>           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>           ports:
>             - containerPort: 8080
>               name: http
>             - containerPort: 8443
>               name: https
>           env:
>             - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
>               value: "true"
> ```

`Service.yaml`

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-keycloak
> spec:
>   selector:
>     app: my-keycloak
>   ports:
>     - port: 8080
>       targetPort: 8080
>       name: http
> ```

`Ingress.yaml`

> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   labels:
>     app: my-keycloak
>   name: my-keycloak-ingress
> spec:
>   rules:
>     - host: mykecloak.com
>       http:
>         paths:
>           - backend:
>               serviceName: my-keycloak
>               servicePort: 8080
> ```

but the base url always set to this, which is false and not work. What i want that the base url should be **https://mykeycloak.com/*** (with https and without the port number)

[current-deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYTWL.jpg)

Many people said that the solution is set the **PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING** to **TRUE**, but it doesnot work for me. Is there something i miss ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do You have?

Comment: hi @PiotrMalec
the K8s version is v.1.16.8-eks

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay I had some time off. Have You managed to solve the issue? Also have You considered deploying Keycloak using helm chart?

Comment: HI @PiotrMalec, it's still exist now. So my current solutions is set the KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL env on deployment, but it does not solve everything. I got some error for IDP login with SAML Protocol, also signing out from account service. I also try to add new configmap data for ingress-nginx controller like this 
`use-forwarded-headers: "true"`
but nothing changes. 

Helm is not an option right now because our organization decides not to use it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path /*

```
- host: mykeycloak.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```